# Relation in contraction of two ideals of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let, $f:A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism. If $J_1$ & $J_2$ be two ideals of $B$ then prove that $\displaystyle J_1^c+J_2^c\subset \left(J_1+J_2\right)^c$, where $I^c$ denotes the contraction of $I$.

Take , $x\in J_1^c+J_2^c. $ Then , $x=x_1+x_2$ for some $x_1\in J_1^c$ and $x_2 \in J_2^c$. Then $f^{-1}(x_1)\in J_1 $ and $f^{-1}(x_2)\in J_2$.

Now if $f$ is given $1-1$ then inverse exists and we have done.

Otherwise how to complete the proof ?

Comment: Are the $I$'s and $J$'s related somehow?

Comment: @Randall Sorry..But there are no given relation.

Comment: Where is it said $f$ is one to one?

Comment: @Bernard I'm saying if it is given that $f$ is $1-1$ then we have done..But unfortunately it is not given..That's why I've stuck here

Comment: You don't need $ f $ to be injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ x_1\in J_1^c $, then by **definition of contraction** $ f(x_1)\in J_1$. Likewise $ f(x_2)\in J_2$. Then $ f(x_1)+f(x_2)=f(x_1+x_2)\in J_1+J_2$. Hence, $ x=x_1+x_2\in (J_1+J_2)^c$.